# Converting code to determine prime numbers from C to Python 3

Tags: python, cs50

I initially wrote the code in C fairly easily, it seems to be bug free. I am struggling to get the same idea to work in Python and I was hoping for some guidance.

For the Python code, I tried not using the cs50 library so I had to take extra measures when getting an integer. I'm finding that it always returns True, even when it says that it is not an integer, it does not return anything when inputting 1 and 2, and it gets all the numbers correct up to 15, which it says it is prime. There must be something wrong in the for loop, but from my understanding of Python for loops the range goes from the first number inclusive to the second number noninclusive.

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("enter a number: ");
    int prime = get_int();

    for (int j = 2; j < prime; j++)
    {
        if (prime % j == 0)
        {
            printf("%i is not a prime number. \n", prime);
            return 0; 
        }

    }

    printf("%i is a prime number. \n", prime);
    return 1;
}
```

and this is my Python code:

```
def main():
    n = get_number()
    m = is_prime(n)

def get_number():
    while True:
        prime = input("enter an integer: ")
        if prime.isdigit():
            prime = int(prime)
            break
    while True:
        if prime >= 1:
            break
    return prime

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("{} is not a prime number".format(n))
            return 1
        print("{} is a prime number".format(n))  
        return 0

 if __name__=="__main__":
     main()
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your second `while True:` loop will repeat infinitely if `prime` is less than 1, since it never updates `prime`.

Comment: You should iterate to square root of n inclusive. Saves time on big numbers

Comment: Indentation of "is a prime number" is too deep. Should be outside the loop. Else returns immediately either way.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @Jean-FrançoisFabre about square root, the code is also inefficient by testing every even divisor. Check if the input is `2` first, if not, iterate with `int sqrtprime = (int)sqrt(prime); for (int j = 3; j <= sqrtprime; j += 2)`. Or with `for (int j = 3; j * j <= prime; j += 2)` but you have to watch out for overflow of `j * j`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the code that says that the number is prime outside the loop, just like in your C version.

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("{} is not a prime number".format(n))
            return 1
    print("{} is a prime number".format(n))  
    return 0
```

Comment: Testing prime up to n is very wasteful

Comment: True, but it's not relevant to the problem in the question. I could also completely rewrite it to use Sieve of Eratosthenes, but that would not explain his mistake.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Your comment above is adequate to address that point.

Comment: Hello @Barmar, thank you for your advice - when taking the last two lines out of the for loop I still only get 0 returned even when it is not a prime a number (I check with the echo $? prompt command). Would you understand why this is the case?

Comment: You're only returning `0` to the place in the script where it calls `main()`, you're not returning it as the process's exit status. Use `sys.exit(main())` to return the value to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most direct translation of your **C** code into Python would be something like:

```
import sys

def get_int(message):

    while True:
        string = input(message)

        if string.isdigit():
            integer = int(string)
            if integer >= 1:
                return integer

def main():

    prime = get_int("enter a number: ")

    for j in range(2, prime):
        if prime % j == 0:
            print("{} is not a prime number".format(prime))
            sys.exit(1)  # failure

    print("{} is a prime number.".format(prime))
    sys.exit(0)  # success

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code is buggy (claims 1 is a prime) and inefficient, just like the original.

**USAGE**

```
> bash
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
enter a number: 13
13 is a prime number.
bash-3.2$ echo $?
0
bash-3.2$ python3 test.py
enter a number: 55
55 is not a prime number
bash-3.2$ echo $?
1
bash-3.2$
```

Although these two lines:

```
print("{} is not a prime number".format(prime))
sys.exit(1)  # failure
```

can be combined into one:

```
sys.exit("{} is not a prime number".format(prime))
```

We don't want to do so for this program as the message would print to `stderr` but in our other exit which can't be combined:

```
print("{} is a prime number.".format(prime))
sys.exit(0)  # success
```

the message prints to `stdout`.  So for consistency, I made them both the same, printing to `stdout` as in the OP's original code.